# Android layouts and icon/view sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have layout-large and on one activity i have listView which height is 270dp and icon 48x48dp. It looks good on tablet (nexus7).
Now I am designing layout for noral screens and small screens. And this icon 48x48dp and 270dp  listview looks very big. How to scale them down according to screen size. What sizes to use?

Answer (score 0):

In your project you have 4 drawable/ folders, u need to use them in order to get the desired result.
Scale your icon to 24x24dp or similiar and place it in drawable-mdpi/ folder. For scaling you can use paint or photoshop.
For more info read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range).
Hope this will help.
however it is good to use match_parent with listView instead of dp.